# In c++, should overloaded operators for a mathematical datatype return new a object of the same type or mutate the existing one?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, immutability

I'm in the process of writing an application in which there is a great need for a mathematical datatype (3d vector).

Currently, my `Vector3` implementation is mainly as follows:

`Vector.h`:

```cpp
class Vector3 {
private:
    double i, j, k;

public:
    Vector3 (double i, double j, double k);

    Vector3 operator+ (const Vector3& other) const;
    // overload other operators as well.


    double getI () const;
    double getJ () const;
    double getK () const;
}
```

Vector3::operator+ is defined in `Vector3.cpp` as follows:

```cpp
Vector3 Vector3::operator+ (const Vector3& other) const {
    return {i + other.i, j + other.j, k + other.k};
}
```

Should my overloaded operators return new objects of the same type, or mutate the object they're called upon? The advice all over the internet is to mutate the objects themselves for performance reasons, but that greatly reduces the expressiveness (and thus, increases proneness to errors) of the code. For example: when an operator+ returns a new object, I can do stuff like:

```cpp
Vector3 a = {0, 0, 1};
Vector3 b = {0, 1, 1};
Vector3 c = {1, 1, 1};

std::cout << a + b << std::endl; // result: {0, 1, 2}
std::cout << a + c << std::endl // result: {1, 1, 2}
```

If `a` were to be modified directly, the second addition would result in `{1, 2, 3}`, correct?

My questions are:

- Have I understood something incorrectly?
- What are the pros and cons of each approach?
- Can I somehow combine the best of the both worlds?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything you could want to know can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: Generally `operator+` should return a copy, not mutate the original object.

Comment: `operator+=(const Vector3&)` should be a member function and should modify the object that it's called on. `Vector3 operator+(const Vector3&, const Vector3&)` should be a non-member function; it should return a new object and should be implemented using `+=`.

Comment: @PeteBecker If `operator+` is implemented using `operator+=`, isn't the original object being mutated, then? This is the part I don't understand

Comment: @K.Raivio The answer to that is sort-of covered in the linked duplicate. What is does is `Vector3 operator+(Vector3, const Vector3&)` and uses the passed-by-value first parameter as the object mutated by `+=`. For `Vector3 operator+(const Vector3&, const Vector3&)` In Pete Becker's comment usually you would make a copy of the first parameter, then mutate and return the copy.